# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.compat' in tensorflow1.4 and python3.6 and cuda 8.0

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, python-3.6

I am trying to run a DL code based.
My set up is :
tensorflow 1.4
python 3.6
cuda 8.0

I am getting all the time the same error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "demo.py", line 285, in <module>
    main()
  File "demo.py", line 55, in main
    import tflearn
  File "/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tflearn/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.compat'



I would appreciate for any help please.
```

Comment: The code you are trying to use was written for TF2. Upgrade your tensorflow version,

Comment: You may use TensorFlow 1.15 or higher

Answer (score 0):

The `tf.compat.v1` module was added in Tf `>=1.13`. Upgrade to `1.14` , `1.15`, or `2.x` and this will work fine.